# Specific non self-adjoint operator for $\mathcal{P}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Given the inner product space $\mathcal{P}^2$ with inner product defined as $(<p,q>) =\int_0^1 p(x)q(x) dx$ and an operator $$T(a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2) = a_1x$$I need to show that the operator is not self-adjoint, but I'm finding that

*ANSWERED: ($$(<Tv,v>) = (<v,Tv>) = \int_0^1 a_0 + a_1^2x^2 + a_2x^2 dx = a_0 + \frac{1}{3}(a_1^2 + a_2)$$ 
What am I doing wrong?)*

I was showing that $<Tv,v> = <v,Tv>$ instead of $<v,Tw>=<w,Tv>$.

**Also, how come even though the conjugate transpose of the matrix of T is T the operator isn't self-adjoint?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to check that for all $v,w\in\mathcal{P}^2$, $(Tv,w)=(v,Tw)$ for "self-adjoint"; not $(Tv,v)=(v,Tv)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider $v=1$ and $w=x$:
$$
\langle T(v),w\rangle=0,\quad
\langle v,T(w)\rangle=\int_0^1x \ dx=\frac12.
$$

Although the matrix for $T$ in the ordered basis $(1,x,x^2)$ is given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which is a symmetric matrix, $T$ is not self-adjoint *with respect to* the inner product space endowed with your inner product.

If you consider the *standard* inner product instead, the $T$ is self-adjoint:

$$
( a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2,b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2):=a_0b_0+a_1b_1+a_2b_2.
$$
Then you have $(Tv,w)=(v,Tw)$ for all $v,w\in\mathcal{P}^2$.

> Denote by $ (\cdot ,\cdot )$  the *standard* inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The real $n$-by-$n$ matrix $A$ is symmetric if and only if
>   $$
> {\displaystyle (Ax,y)=(x,Ay)\quad \forall x,y\in {\mathbb {R} }^{n}.}
> $$